# Can we use :not selector on hidden element?

Tags: css-selectors

I created list with some elements as display:block and rest with display:none.
Tried to apply search on whole list but it resulted the set from visible list instead of complete list.

So how can I search in whole list in below eg.?

```
<ul>
<li class="searchable show" data-index="ajay">ajay</li>
<li class="searchable show" data-index="amit">amit</li>
<li class="searchable hide" data-index="ashish">ashish</li>
<li class="searchable hide" data-index="ali">ali</li>
<li class="searchable show" data-index="xyz">xyz</li>
</ul>
```

When I apply style by:

```
.searchable:not([data-index*=\"" + val + "\"]) {
   display: none;
}
// where val=a; since I am searching by a
```

It resulted in:

```
ajay
amit
```

Instead expected result was:

```
ajay
amit
ashish
ali
```

Comment: None of the above list items have `data-index` attribute.

Comment: no i added in list as: <li id="employeeList_0" class="searchable show" data-index="ajay">

Comment: You're using variables in your CSS, do you generate the CSS rule(s) serverside or clientside (rendering it into `<style>` sections) or do you declare them in CSS?

Comment: i am rendering in style tag. It was working fine when i used display block to whole list but not working in above case when some are hidden

Comment: @KhushbuPareek There's no string concatenation in CSS therefore the syntax is invalid. If you're using JavaScript, you could select the list items by `document.querySelectorAll()` and change each of items' display to none through a loop on the nodeList.

Comment: The situation is: i have whole list but due to pagination i am showing 1st ten item nd rest are hidden but when you search it should be whole list not in 1st ten which are visible on page. Syntax wise its fine and working when i show whole elements instead of hiding some.

Comment: Note that your `.hide` rules probably make the items hidden even if the `:not()` criteria is fullfilled.

Comment: @KhushbuPareek - this is a situation where posting *all of the css* related to the issue would be helpful. [I'm getting the expected results](http://jsfiddle.net/wahwahwah/repasv8z/5/) when trying to create a simple reproduction based on your comments.

Comment: wahwahwah, your CSS is wrong, it need to be `.searchable.hide` and `.searchable.show` (no space).

Comment: @try-catch-finally: i guess you are right. i ll try by removing that while searching.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.hide` rules will still hide the elements that match the criteria of your `:not([...])` selector.

Assuming your `.show` and `.hide` rules look this ...

```
.searchable.show {
    display: block;
}

.searchable.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

... in cojunction with your rule ...

```
.searchable:not([data-index*="a"]) {
   display: none;
}
```

... you still need a rule like this to make hidden items, that meet the criteria, visible:

```
.hide[data-index*="a"] {
   display: block;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x5py4c5j/